# IP being masked, mysteriously

Tags: services, tor, ip

I'm running Ubuntu with Cinnamon. When checking my IP I noticed it is being masked. I have done nothing to set this, other than installing Tor. But - I am not starting up Tor, yet is it still running somehow, even from a reboot where I did not start Tor.

Looking at my system with Firestarter I see Tor is running.

How could Tor (or some aspects of it) be running on it's own? How can I shut it off? I see no mention of Tor under system processes that are running.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have Tor either from [Ubuntu archives](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/tor) or from the [Tor archives](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) installed. They install Tor as a daemon. This means the software is started automatically on every boot. You'll find a start script in `/etc/init.d/tor`.

You basically have two options to shut it off:

1. Uninstall Tor
2. Remove Tor from the startup

For the second case you can use `bum`, the bootup manager. Maybe this is not installed. So you have to install it first. Then you open `bum` as root and look for the entry `tor`. Make a right-click and select *Deactivate & apply now*:
[image: screenshot of bum and clicked on tor]
Now Tor will not start automatically, but only when you want it to start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the IP is going through a proxy like Tor and you're not just confusing your internal and external IP addresses? Try making sure that Tor isn't listed as a startup program, and check this site from the Tor project to be sure that it is Tor that's running https://check.torproject.org

Comment: The sites says Tor is running. How do I check what programs run at startup?